# How could I implement a pendelum to stabilize my player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I want my character to act like a pendulum when he lands on the ground to stabilize himself. (Like this game does it: [Basket Random](https://www.twoplayergames.org/game/basket-random), when a character lands he begins to swing until he comes to a full stop). How can I achieve this kind of pendulum? Im using a Rigidbody on my character, so a Hinge Joint wouldn't work since the hinge is gravity dependent. Unfortunately, I don't have any idea how to implement this so I have no code to show.

So the procedure would look like this: 
[image: Player lands on ground] 
Player lands on the ground 
[image: Player starts swinging] 
Player starts swinging 
[image: Player swings in other direction] 
Player swings in the other direction with less momentum 
[image: The process repeats itself until the player stops swinging] 
The process repeats itself until the player lost his momentum and stops swinging.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: move the center of mass to the bottom, or even below the bottom, of the character's rigid body.

Answer (score 0):

As @Leo Bartkus (Thanks a lot Leo) pointed out I only had to adjust the center of mass below my character. If you don't know how this works, check out this tutorial: [Center of mass tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2VOu5d2wVM)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).